# Help trying to implement a request object factory

Tags: c#, design, design-patterns, object-oriented-design, implementations

Heres my issue. I have different types of methods which make HTTP requests to a REST api. To keep things clean, I have methods that take different types of request objects as parameters. Example below.

```
Task<IEventResponse> FindEventAsync(IGetEventsRequest data, CancellationToken token);
```

So everytime my controller calls this method, it has to create a object of type IGetEventsRequest. Creating a new() instance of its implementation feels dumb, and I started thinking about creating a generic factory which could create these objects for me, and also work for all kinds of object types. Any help how could I achieve this?

I am looking for this kind of syntax:

```
await FindEventsAsync(_requestFactory.Create(?somehow specify the type of this and generate a new object based on the type), CancelationToken.None);
```

Comment: How do those `different types of request objects as parameters` relate to `IGetEventsRequest data` you want to create? What is the `IGetEventsRequest`, so it can be used for any request? If `IGetEventsRequest` is just a set of key-value pairs, while request objects are plain [DTOs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) you can use a bit of reflection to generate the set from input object properties, and then initialize some `class GenericGetEventsRequest: IGetEventsRequest` with that data.

Comment: Usually type parameters to be instantiated are implemented as generic type parameters, but a Type can be passed instead, using reflection to instantiate. Another technique is to pass a delegate that creates an instance as needed. See Func.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite seeing why this is a challenge. Here is a barebones example.

```
interface IGetEventsRequest
{
}

class SomeRequest : IGetEventsRequest
{
    //Your implementation here
}

class RequestFactory
{
    public T Create<T>() where T: IGetEventsRequest, new()
    {
        T o = new T();
        //Add initialization code here
        return o;
    }
}

class Example
{
    private readonly RequestFactory _requestFactory;

    public Example(RequestFactory requestFactory)
    {
        _requestFactory = requestFactory;
    }

    void Test()
    {
        await FindEventsAsync(_requestFactory.Create<SomeRequest>(), CancelationToken.None);
    }
}
```